# Which coding abbreviations is widely used and generally understood?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

Sometimes it is difficult to invent short and accurate name for a method or variable that is clear on the first glance. Abbreviations are not recommended today. But, for instance, if we use

- `src` and `dest` in function params, it is contextually clear what they mean
- `i` often means index: `for(int i=0; i<size; i++)`.

Are there any other abbreviations like these used in more than one language?

Comment: Au contraire: 'i' generally means 'index' -- and there is the heart of the problem.

Comment: Correct. But the name `i` is often used in `for`. I can't see the problem.

Comment: The problem is that the idea of a holy book of abbreviations (etc) for universal usage is flawed from the start -- there will never be universal agreement on its contents.  The lack of the possibility of a such agreement has already gained this question 3 votes to close.

Comment: I don't think so. For instance, we use LA for Los Angeles. It can surely mean Language-Agnostic or Lack of Ability, it depends on domain, as jammon pointed out. The domain is programming itself. Or maybe - is it too wide domain?

Comment: Jan: who is this 'we' of which you write ?  'You' may use LA for Los Angeles, I may use it for lanthanum.  The domain is not programming itself, it is the set of things about which programs are written.  It is the (essentially) infinite nature of that set which defies attempts to define universal agreement on abbreviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of abbreviations that are common and generally understood ("args", "i18n", "HTTP", …).

I'm not sure if I get your question right, less that there is a good answer to it. A good abbreviation is short (dooh) and easily understood by the readers. So the choice of an abbreviation depends on audience; what is obvious for a particle physicist might seem far fetched for a finance analytic or a games developer.

Maybe, the misleading word is abbreviation. The choice of a good abbreviation is the same problem of naming things in general (which is known as one of the [two hard things in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)). Readability is more important than conciseness.

Conclusion: if you know your audience (and your problem domain of course), you should be able to find understandable (and not too long) namings.

[Update]

Robert Martin wrote a whole 14-page chapter on "Meaningful Names" in his book on [Clean Code](http://www.e-reading.org.ua/bookreader.php/134601/Clean_Code_-_A_Handbook_of_Agile_Software_Craftsmanship.pdf), which for me is a Must-Read for every serious developer.